# Is there a way to automate the generation of PowerPoint slides?

Tags: database, automation, powerpoint

I have a bunch of data in a database and I want to generate some tables in PowerPoint.  I had started doing this manually but I thought there might be a way I can simply write some code to take my data from the database and output it onto a PowerPoint slide.

Any advice here?

Comment: try www.pptxbuilder.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly automate powerpoint trough the use of its XPCOM api -- 
(although, everytime I looked for documentation on the COM API for MS Office I haven't found it)

But, I'd suggest that instead of creating PowerPoint slides, you created Open Document presentations (ISO 26300 - .ODT files) - which are easy to undestand, parse and edit programatically -

.ODT files are the default presentation format for Open Office, Koffice, and other office software, and I think that Microsoft has come to support it by now - (although they have pushed ISO to approve their own proprietary specification of a similar format)

Anyway, editing the contents of a .odp file is trivial; the ODP file itself is a zipped archive, you unzip it, and edit the "contents.xml" file inside it -- creating new slides is a matter of copying the XML node corresponding to a slide and editing the desired text -- 
and pack everything inside a zip archive again.

Comment: Powerpoint has a COM interface, not XPCOM.  I think XPCOM is Mozilla's implementation of COM, and they built it into Firefox if I'm not mistaken. That's completely irrelevant to powerpoint. Getting back to the question...Yes, it is quite possible to programmatically generate powerpoint presentations, using jscript or vbscript. Microsoft calls it "automation" and the COM moniker to search for is `Application.Powerpoint`.

Answer (score 2):

PowerPoint has access to VBA right? ([It does, I checked](http://www.google.com/search?q=powerpoint+vba&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a))  So, you should be able to automate the generation that way.  I've done this pretty extensively but in to an excel document. I've never tried it with power point.

The problem now becomes one of time investment? Learn how to do it with VBA or do it manually... If this could be a common thing, I'd suggest you learn how to do it via VBA. Generally speaking, I found that automating Excel with VBA was not too hard once you understood the basics. The time saved was definitely worth it in the long run.

Finally, I wish I could recommend a book to get you started, but alas, I've never considered trying this so I've never put anytime in researching this.

Comment: This is the ultimate answer that answers every question. So, -1.

Answer (score 2):

- you can generate Powerpoint files with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) (a java library)
- [python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a python library for creating and updating PowerPoint files
- OpenOffice has an interface called [UNO](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Uno/FAQ#Can_you_give_me_some_example_code.3F) with bindings in several languages

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest route to take would be to use Excel to extract the data and then embed the spreadsheet in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you listed ODT (or a spare intern) is the best solution. Especially if you just need this 1 or 2 times and/or how it looks in the final PPT is not important.

However, if this grows to be a situation where you have complex logic for what is pulled, or you want to have maore control over how the output looks and give non-programmers the ability to create/edit the templates used, then take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/) (disclaimer - I'm the CTO at Windward). With Windward you can design reports in PowerPoint that pull data from multipel datasources to then generate the final PowerPoint with the data incorporated.

Answer (score -2):

Only for once or twice you can use excel. Place data in excel and generate tables. Then copy and paste it in your power point. Easy way but not an exact tool.